# How to capture the text for the pop up given in Red box in image

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

How to capture the text for the pop up given in Red box on image?

Comment: Please see if this is helpful - http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-verify-tooltip-text-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: I don't think you can get this value with `selenium` as it's not part of `DOM`. Browser will trigger this tooltip on each `onmouseover` event if `"required"` attribute present in `input` field located inside `form`

Comment: Yes it is coming from `required` html tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required
Please see the link